# Python optimisation of dataframe columns

Tags: python, optimization

I am trying to learn optimisation in python and am looking for some guidance on how best to approach this optimisation scenario below (what libraries and pseudo code would be best)

I have a dataframe with two value columns min number and max number.

I want to create a third column which is a value restricted to be between the other two columns.

The total sum of all rows in this new third column column must be equal to a defined variable.

If possible, I would like to evenly distribute the numeric distribution between the other two columns (min and max) and hence contribution to the defined variable.

Any input whatsoever would be greatly appreciated. Even a reference to a video series on youtube or any other learning material.

Comment: Do you want the values in the 3rd column to be evenly (as much as possible) distributed amongst themselves, or each relatively to the min/max of its row ?

Comment: Preferably relative to the min/max of their row

Comment: Then it seems it's more a (trivial) mathematical problem than an optimization one: basic proportionality works: var (your defined variable) must be between sum(min) and sum(max), and the optimal value for each row i is min(i)*var/sum(min) (or max(i)*var/sum(max)).

Comment: @Swifty yeah I suppose you're right. I was looking for an excuse to use optimization but you're solution is perfectly valid.